# Holding a key (wasd and spacebar) presses more then once most of the Time

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, keyboard

I'm playing a lot of Minecraft KitPVP and when I, for example, hold the W key it mostly presses more than once.
That is not good because I lose to a lot of people just because of that.
I play Minecraft Java with Badlion Client. *mostly 1.8.9*
Please does anyone know a Solution?
If yes then, please put them.

Comment: Wdym "holding W it presses more than once", do you mean its rapidly going forward and stopping or what do you mean?

Comment: It's a problem with my keyboard I think, I plugged it out and back in and it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but it might be something with your keyboard and its plug. You could check if the keyboard is completely plugged in or if the keys are broken.
It could also be if your Minecraft window is selected because on my mac if the window isn't selected it takes more than one click or movement to select and move.
Sorry if this doesn't help